# How to verify a passport . Can someone help me?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, can someone help me with this error

```
from passporteye import read_mrz
import pytesseract as tess

tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER-DAF005\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
mrz = read_mrz("test.PNG")

mrz_data = mrz.to_dict()


nationality = str('Nationality :' + mrz_data['nationality'])
nationality = str(nationality)
print(nationality)

name = str('Given Name :' + mrz_data['names'])
names = str(name)
print(name)

surname = str('Surname :' + mrz_data['surname'])
surname = str(surname)
print(surname)

typePassp = str('Passport type :' + mrz_data['type'])
type = str(type)
print(typePassp)

country = str('Country code :' + mrz_data['country'])
country = str(country)
print(country)

birth = str('Date of birth :' + mrz_data['date_of_birth'])
birth = str(birth)
print(birth)

idNum = str('ID Number :' + mrz_data['personal_number'])
idNum = str(idNum)
print(idNum)

passNum = str('Passport Number :' + mrz_data['number'])
passNum = str(passNum)
print(passNum)

sex = str('Gender :' + mrz_data['sex'])
sex = str(sex)
print(sex)

expDate = str('Expiration date :' + mrz_data['expiration_date'])
expDate = str(expDate)
print(expDate)

print(mrz_data, file=open('passportdata.csv', "a"))

from mrz.generator.td3 import TD3CodeGenerator


code = TD3CodeGenerator(typePassp, country, surname, name, passNum, nationality, birth, sex, expDate, idNum)
result = str(code)
print(result)
```

The error message :

```
C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/USER-DAF005/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectMRZ/reconnaissance.py
Nationality :GAB
Given Name :AUSTEN JUNIOR
Surname :MOUITY CAKPO
Passport type :P<
Country code :GAB
Date of birth :900218
ID Number :<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Passport Number :15GA84817
Gender :M
Expiration date :210803

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\reconnaissance.py", line 61, in <module>
    code = TD3CodeGenerator(typePassp, country, surname, name, passNum, nationality, birth, sex, expDate, idNum)
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\venv\lib\site-packages\mrz\generator\td3.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.document_type = document_type
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\venv\lib\site-packages\mrz\generator\_fields.py", line 46, in document_type
    self._document_type = check.document_type(value, self) if not self.force \
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\venv\lib\site-packages\mrz\base\string_checkers.py", line 94, in document_type
    raise DocumentTypeError(cause=string)
mrz.base.errors.DocumentTypeError: ('String was not recognized as a valid type of document.', 'Passport type :P<')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. _Is_ `:P<` correct, or is it the result of an OCR failure?

Comment: All of these `str` conversions in the code are redundant. If you were able to do `'x' + y`, then the result *already was* a string, so writing `var = str('x' + y)` accomplishes nothing different from `var = 'x' + y`; and going on with `var = str(var)` again does nothing useful. You should also read up on string formatting in Python - if you were having problems before trying to make `+` work with strings and throwing `str` around randomly trying to fix type errors, then you are *not learning the intended lesson* and need to stop and read how to do it properly.

Comment: it displays the data but it does not want to display the passport code

Comment: The docs at https://pypi.org/project/mrz/ are a good place to start to understand which values are/aren't valid. I'd suggest you dig into the libraries you're using _before_ asking questions here.

Comment: `type` is not a good name to use for a variable, because it is a builtin in python..  You do `type = str(type)` but don't actually have a variable named type.  Maybe you meant typePassP?

Comment: :P< is correct but  the result of an OCR fail

Answer (score 0):

You have created strings for printing that include the field label as well as the value:

```
typePassp = str('Passport type :' + mrz_data['type'])
```

This is fine for printing, but corrupts the values for all future use.  Just pass `mrz_data['type']` directly.

Comment: it gives me this error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER-DAF005\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectMRZ\test_tesseract.py", line 20, in <module>
    code = TD3CodeGenerator(country_code='country')
TypeError: __init__() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'document_type', 'surname', 'given_names', 'document_number', 'nationality', 'birth_date', 'sex', and 'expiry_date'